# Filtering and creating new columns by condensing the lists for each item information

Tags: python, apache-spark

I am trying to improve my programming skills at work (analyst) and one of the engineering projects I worked is around ETL. Essentially, we roll up all individuals account information to a single row for each user and their purchases are converted to a list. There are two different logics which uses different columns for rollups with a slightly different way for performing the conversion. This is done by splitting the data initially and then combined. I wrote PySpark code (first time) and was hoping that the experts here can give me some feedback before I share it with my manager. It's a new job, so I really hope that I can give my best.

Here are the example of what I was trying to accomplish with my code alongside it. My manager is hoping for 'modular' and 'refactored' code. I have tried my best to follow pep-8 style, but apart from that, I am unsure as to how to improve this code.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F


# Load the trade files from the filestore
adfe_df = df1


# Drop the account column since each account has a different token every time we get new data (monthly data)
adfe_df = adfe_df.drop('Col1')

# Drop duplicate Rows - Rows are duplicated every time we get new data
adfe_df = adfe_df.dropDuplicates()

adfe_df = adfe_df.orderBy('Col2')
adfe_df2 = adfe_df.filter(F.col("Col3").isNotNull())
adfe_df3 = adfe_df.filter(F.col("Col3").isNull() & F.col('Col4').isNotNull())

# Grouping by account information and creating lists for all the variables we care about
adfe_df2 = adfe_df2\
                    .groupBy('Col5')\
                    .agg(
                        F.collect_list('Col6').alias('Col6'),
                        F.collect_list('Col7').alias('Col7'),
                        F.collect_list('Col8').alias('Col8'),
                        F.collect_list('Col9').alias('1'),
                        )

# Creating a list of colummns we want to split --> Payment_tracking_cycle_*
columns = adfe_df2.select('1',).columns

# Collects the sizes of each colum in consideration  
adfe_df2_sizes = adfe_df2.select(*[F.size(col).alias(col) for col in columns])

# Get the max number of columns from each column
adfe_df2_max = adfe_df2_sizes.agg(*[F.max(col).alias(col) for col in columns])

# Pick the first element in each of the max array size length
max_dict = adfe_df2_max.collect()[0].asDict()

# Splitting the columns into multiple columns and renaming the columns to "AB" + x + y format
adfe_df2_result = adfe_df2.select('Col6',
                                  'Col7',
                                  'Col8',
                                  '1', *[adfe_df2[col][i].alias("AB" + str(i + 1) + col) for col in columns for i in range(max_dict[col])])

adfe_df2_result.cache()


# Converting the column values to bool (columns store actual values currently)
adfe_df3 = adfe_df3\
                    .withColumn('Col10', F.when(adfe_df3['Col10'] > 0, 1)
                        .otherwise(adfe_df3['Col10']))\

# Grouping by account information and creating lists for all the variables we care about
adfe_df3 = adfe_df3.groupBy('Col5')\
                    .agg(
                        F.collect_list('Col6').alias('Col6'),
                        F.collect_list('Col7').alias('Col7'),
                        F.collect_list('Col8').alias('Col8'),
                        F.collect_list('Col10').alias('2'),
                        )



# Creating a list of colummns we want to split --> Payment_tracking_cycle_*
columns = adfe_df3.select('2',).columns

# Collects the sizes of each colum in consideration  
adfe_df3_sizes = adfe_df3.select(*[F.size(col).alias(col) for col in columns])

# Get the max number of columns from each column
adfe_df3_max = adfe_df3_sizes.agg(*[F.max(col).alias(col) for col in columns])

# Pick the first element in each of the max array size length
max_dict = adfe_df3_max.collect()[0].asDict()

# Splitting the columns into multiple columns and renaming the columns to "AB" + x + y format
adfe_df3_max_result = adfe_df3.select('Col6',
                                  'Col7',
                                  'Col8',
                                  'Col9', *[adfe_df3[col][i].alias("AB" + str(i + 1) + col) for col in columns for i in range(max_dict[col])])

adfe_df3_result.cache()


# Create a list of all the unique columns in the two tables
adfe_df2_result_cols = adfe_df2_result.columns
adfe_df3_result_cols = adfe_df3_result.columns

all_abxy_list = list( set(adfe_df2_result_cols) | set(adfe_df3_result_cols))


# Verify if the column is present in the dataframe, if it is missing, create the null column with that name and cast with type 'int' for consistency
for column in all_abxy_list:
  if column not in adfe_df2_result_cols.columns:
     = adfe_df2_result_cols.withColumn(column, F.lit(None).cast('int'))
  if column not in adfe_df3_result_cols.columns:
    adfe_df3_result_cols = adfe_df3_result_cols.withColumn(column, F.lit(None).cast('int'))

# Join the two tables for the final ABxy table for the accounts that have either pieces of information

adfe_abxy= (adfe_df2_result_cols.union(adfe_df3_result_cols))
```

Answer (score 1):

Old active question, but I hope I can still help with my insights on how I would refactor the code.

1. **I would start by removing declarative comments** ("this does x" type of comments).

   There are a couple of reasons why, but the main ones are that the comments will lead eventually to confusion because technology evolves and the code evolves with it, so the comment might not hold true.

   Code is written for developers, so you should assume that who is going to read knows about the technology, so a "this does x" type of comment does nothing to help with readability. Over time, people start by ignoring the comment, and valuable information can be ignored.
2. **I would try to avoid reserved keywords like `columns` without being within a separate context** (inside a function for example) because it might make it harder to find bugs down the line.
3. **I would create small functions** to avoid code duplication and reuse as much code as possible.
4. **I would `unpersist` cached data frames after using** to avoid OOM.

This is a proposal of refactoring; keep in mind I haven't tested it, but I hope it helps:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

def remove_duplicate_accounts(df):
    unique_records = ((F.col("Col3").isNotNull()) & (F.col('Col4').isNotNull()))
    df = (
        df.drop("Col1")
          .dropDuplicates()
          .orderBy('Col2') # TODO: Check if this orderBy is needed?
          .filter(unique_records)
    )
    return df


def create_account_information(df, group_column, column_aliases):
    columns_to_collect = [F.collect(x).alias(y) for x,y in column_aliases.items()]
    df = (
        df.groupBy(group_column)
          .agg(columns_to_collect)
    )
    return df
    
    
def transform_columns_to_custom_format(df, column_order, start_col_to_rearrange):
    input_columns = rearrange_columns(df, start_col_to_rearrange)
    max_dict = get_dictionary_of_account_max_values(df, input_columns)
    
    custom_format = [
        df[col][i].alias("AB" + str(i + 1) + col) 
        for col in input_columns 
        for i in range(max_dict[col])
    ]
    custom_selection = column_order + custom_format
    return df.select(*custom_selection)


def rearrange_columns(df, start_col):
    return df.select(start_col, ).columns   


def get_dictionary_of_account_max_values(df, input_columns):
    df = df.select(*[F.size(col).alias(col) for col in input_columns]) 
    df = df.agg(*[F.max(col).alias(col) for col in input_columns])
    return df.collect()[0].asDict()      


def create_flag_column(df):
    is_bigger_than_zero = F.when(df['Col10'] > 0, 1).otherwise(df['Col10'])
    return df.withColumn("Col10", is_bigger_than_zero)


def union_dataframes(left_side, right_side):
    all_columns = union_sets(left_side, right_side)
    left, right = create_missing_columns(left_df, right_df, all_columns)
    return left.union(right)


def union_sets(left_side, right_side):
    return list(set(left_side.columns) | set(right_side.columns))    


def create_missing_columns(left_df, right_df, all_columns):
    new_column = F.lit(None).cast('int')
    for column in all_columns:
        if column not in left_df.columns:
            left_df = left_df.withColumn(column, new_column)
        elif column not in right_df.columns:
            right_df = right_df.withColumn(column, new_column)
    return left_df, right_df


ACCOUNT_ALIASES = {
    "Col6": "Col",
    "Col7": "Col7",
    "Col8": "Col8",
    "Col9": "1",
}

FLAGGED_ACCOUNTS_ALIASES = {
    "Col6": "Col",
    "Col7": "Col7",
    "Col8": "Col8",
    "Col10": "2",
}

IDENTIFIER = "Col5"
ACCOUNT_REARRANGE_COLUMN = "1"
FLAGGED_ACCOUNT_REARRANGE_COLUMN = "2"

accounts = remove_duplicate_accounts(df1)
accounts = create_account_information(accounts, IDENTIFIER, ACCOUNT_ALIASES)
accounts = transform_columns_to_custom_format(accounts, ACCOUNT_ALIASES.keys(), ACCOUNT_REARRANGE_COLUMN)
accounts.cache()

flagged_accounts = create_flag_column(accounts)                                    
flagged_accounts = create_account_information(flagged_accounts, IDENTIFIER, FLAGGED_ACCOUNTS_ALIASES)     
flagged_accounts = transform_columns_to_custom_format(flagged_accounts, FLAGGED_ACCOUNTS_ALIASES.keys(), FLAGGED_ACCOUNT_REARRANGE_COLUMN)
flagged_accounts.cache()

final_accounts = union_dataframes(accounts, flagged_accounts)
accounts.unpersist()
flagged_accounts.unpersist()
```